# Default Ruby version on OSX Lion ? Still 1.8.x or 1.9.x?

Tags: ruby, macos

What's the default Ruby version on OSX Lion ? Still 1.8.x or 1.9.x ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pre-release of Lion:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

Comment: how about adding whether `find /usr -name '*.rb'` still returns a bunch of files. Snow Leopard installs software that needs the Apple installed Ruby and I'm curious whether they've continued that.

Comment: The OS X GM build ships with MRI 1.8.7

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as lion just released today, i would like to answer "the Tin Man", in short -- yes, there is still a bunch of files installed when you do `find /usr -name '*.rb'`

Oddly enough, Rails is not installed by default, i am running with GM so it might be that release is different... *shrugs*